# Node.js socket send and receive simultaneously

Tags: node.js, sockets, audio, streaming

I'm not used to node.js and I need an advice.
I need to create a client being able to open a socket connection to an already built Java server and then to capture and send audio from microphone. In the same time, the client could receive some text messages from the server. The server is able to receive the incoming audio stream and to send text back to the client in the same time, but I don't know if the same thing is possible also in node.js.

How could a node.js client to write and read from a socket connection simultaneously without remaining blocked? I suppose the read() and write() functions should run in parallel. This task in Java is solved using two threads, but I know node.js is single threaded.

I succeded so far to install some node modules to record audio and to save it as a file on disk. Also I succeded to open a socket and send those files to server, receiving back the text messages. Now I only need this process to be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node.js is asynchronous by nature, typically you ask system to write to the socket and provide callback for operation complete. So function socket.write will not block other code.

```
socket.write("Something", function() {
   // Something is written to the socket... what next?
});

socket.on("data", function(data) {
   // Handle new portion of data
});
```

Comment: The `"data"` callback only gets called for when data gets _received_ on the socket, not when data is written, right? What I'm essentially asking is if, since you provided the unnamed callback function to `socket.write()`, it in turn _won't_ call the `"data"` callback?

Comment: @villapx right "data" event is emitted only when data is received from socket and is not related to writing.